# How to update two values before triggering Worksheet_Change?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested

I am trying to insert two ranges "x" amount of times based on the input from the user.

The user chooses:
-how many mounts they need "D22" and a range is copied and inserted x amount of times,
-then how many "bobbins" they need "D23" and a range is copied and inserted x amount of times.

If there is already a value in "D23" and a new number is typed into "D22" then the code will work.

However if the cells are blank and a value is typed into both "D22" and "D23", only the range for "D22" will populate.

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim NM As Long
    Dim NB As Long
    Dim FL As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim M As Variant
    Dim CheckVal As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Calculation")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Hidden 1")

    NM = sht1.Range("D22").Valu
    sht1.Range("A27:F27").Resize(NM + 100).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    i = NM 'where to find the value for how many mounts
               
    NB = sht1.Range("D23").Value
    j = NB 'where to find the value for how many bobbins
    
    a = 1
    Do Until a > i
        sht2.Range("A38:F41").Copy 'select the range you want to copy

        With sht1.Range("A27").Insert
            a = a + 1
          
            If a > i Then Exit Do
        End With
    Loop
    
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set R = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(lRow, lCol).Offset(2, 0).Address)
          
    b = 1
    Do Until b > j
          
        sht2.Range("A43:F46").Copy 'select the range you want to copy
          
        With R.Insert
            b = b + 1
        End With
    Loop

    End If
          
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: when you have a loop with specific start and end indexes, its much easier and better to use a [For loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement). Instead of `b = 1: Do Until b > j` you can just say `For b = 1 To j`

Comment: You're making Worksheet changes inside a Worksheet_Change event. This will create an infinite loop. You need to set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before making worksheet changes inside the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting these two ideas into their own separate macros. They can individually be triggered by different cells being changed on the worksheet by monitoring the `Worksheet_Change` event and checking `Target`.

[Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) returns any cells that are shared by the two ranges. This is a quick way to check one if the changed cells in the event was D22 or D23. If it was, Intersect will not be `Nothing`, because it will be D22 or D23!

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D22")) Is Nothing Then
        InsertMounts Me.Range("D22").Value
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D23")) Is Nothing Then
        InsertBobbins Me.Range("D23").Value
    End If
End Sub

Sub InsertMounts(Amount As Long)
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Calculation")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Hidden 1")
    
    For a = 1 To Amount
        sht2.Range("A38:F41").Copy 'select the range you want to copy
        sht1.Range("A27").Insert
    Next
    
End Sub
Sub InsertBobbins(Amount As Long)
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Calculation")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Hidden 1")
    
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long, R As Range
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set R = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(lRow, lCol).Offset(2, 0).Address)
    
    For b = 1 To Amount
        sht2.Range("A43:F46").Copy 'select the range you want to copy
        R.Insert
    Next
End Sub
```